# What happens if glutPostRedisplay() is called too quickly?

Tags: opengl, graphics, glut

I am writing an OpenGL program with GLUT, which displays some moving objects in a scene. Rendering is done using my function `Render()`. However, I also want to move the positions of these objects on every loop, and this is done in my function `Step()`.

Now, I tried running a loop which, on each loop, calls `Render()`, followed by `Step()`, and then `glutPostRedisplay()`. However, this did not work; the displayed window was not responsive.

I figured that this was because I also need to run `glutMainLoop()` so that GLUT continually makes the window responsive. Therefore, I need a timer function which is called on every frame, and updates the object positions and renders them. So, I am now using the `glutTimerFunc(...)` for this purpose, as follows:

```
glutDisplayFunc(Render);
glutTimerFunc(3, Step, 0);
glutMainLoop();
```

My understanding of this is that every 3ms, it will call my `Step()` function. If I now add a call to `glutPostRedisplay()` at the end of `Step()`, my program runs fine and the objects move about as expected.

However, what I am wondering is what happens when it takes longer than 3ms to make all the changes to my object positions. In that case, my program will still be processing that last call to `Step()` when the next call to `Step()` is made. This will result in a backlog of `Step()` calls waiting to be processed.

How should I deal with this? Is the only way to increase from 3ms to a larger number? Or are there other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

`glutPostRedisplay()` just sets a flag. It kind of works like this:

```
int do_display = 0;

void glutPostRedisplay(void) {
    do_display = 1;
}

void glutMainLoop(void) {
    for(;;) {
        event ev = get_OS_event();
        switch(ev.type) {
        case keyboard_event: call_keyboard_function(ev); return;
        case mouse_event:    call_mouse_function(ev); return;
        /* ... */
        }
        if( do_display ) {
            call_display_function();
            do_display = 0;
        } else {
            call_idle_function();
        }
    }
}
```

So, you can call `glutPostRedisplay` as much as you want, as long as you don't give the mainloop a chance to process all pending events it will not actually call your display function.

> Therefore, I need a timer function which is called on every frame, and updates the object positions and renders them.

No, what you want is an idle function that advances the animation and  calls `glutPostRedisplay`.

> However, what I am wondering is what happens when it takes longer than 3ms to make all the changes to my object positions. In that case, my program will still be processing that last call to Step() when the next call to Step() is made.

No, because timers don't introduce concurrency. What happens is, that timer events are piling up. However using timers for controlling animation is a bad idea. Instead you should measure the time between invocations of your step function and advance the animation according to the time differential. Also to minimize latency you should not implement an animation step right in the display function so that you're drawing with the most recent animation stepping.